# ssh scp command copies files from remote to remote but not to local machine

Tags: ssh, scp

I need help with this one please. I couldn't connect with any FTP client to a remote server given by a client. It would be SFTP protocol, but I could never connect.

With `ssh user@login.microsites.companyname.com` I'm able to connect.
After connecting I can use `ls` to list the directories and I get `prod dev stage` which refers to the three sudomains.

If I go inside `prod` I get `www tmp log`.

My task would be to copy the remote www directory to my local machine. However I'm not able to.

My idea was after ssh connection to `scp user@login.microsites.companyname.com:/prod/www /Desktop` which should copy the files to my local Desktop.

However what it does is copying the files to the remote machine creating a directory "Desktop" which has the copied files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have gotten things muddled up. You are already on your remote server, so the /Desktop refers to /Desktop on the remote server, not your local machine, essentially you're taking a long way round there and copying the file locally to a different path on the server. Instead, you either need to change the command or change where you are running it from.

Option 1. From the server after sshing in:

```
scp -r /path/to/your/folder user@yourlocalmachine:/Desktop
```

Option 2. From your local machine (easier)

```
scp -r user@login.microsites.companyname.com:/prod/www /Desktop
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. If I use option 2 though … it asks me for the password, when entering I get `scp: /prod/www: No such file or directory`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I hadn't realised you wanted the whole folder. You'd need to use -r (Recursively copy entire directories). I've updated my answer to add this in.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, but no luck either: See https://imgur.com/FGyiXGr
Maybe this has todo with the fact that I couldn't connect with sftp either?

Comment: Is there actually a /prod/www directory? You need to put the full path from root, so if prod is actually under /var/ for example, then you would need to change it to /var/prod/www. Go to the folder and run pwd to make sure you have the full path to the folder and you're not missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your need to run your `scp` command on your computer, not the remote one. Or you have to qualify the destination `Desktop` with the appropriate user name and address.